# ReleaseManager extension security requirements

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009, release-process

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 with a DTAP setup. Content porter plays a significant role in our day-to-day operations. The 2013 Bundles concept will help us solve most our issues.

In the current version, I am trying to install and use [Release Manager extension](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/Releasemanager.aspx) to automate content porting and deployments for a few websites. Installation was successful but I have a couple of questions around the usage.

1. Are there any end point URL changes to the Release Management Configuration specific for SDL 2011 SP1?
2. What is the security right that grants users to perform Release Management?

Answer (score 3):

**PART 1:**
Tridion 2011 SP1 (and possibly also Tridion 2013) should continue to work on:

```
<endpoint address="http://YOUR.SDLTRIDIONCMS.ADDRESS/webservices/CoreService.svc/wsHttp_2010" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp_2010" contract="coreService.ISessionAwareCoreService2010" name="wsHttp_2010"> 
  <identity> 
   <dns value="localhost"/> 
  </identity> 
 </endpoint>
```

Looking at Bart's answer [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/646/71), I think that the endpoint you would need for 2013 (if the endpoint above doesn't work) is:

```
<endpoint name="wsHttp_2012" address="http://localhost/webservices/CoreService2012.svc/wsHttp" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttp" contract="Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.ISessionAwareCoreService">
  <identity>
    <dns value="localhost" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>
```

(Do not be put off by the incorrect year numbers.)

-

**PART 2:** I do not know the definitive answer, but as Release Manager uses the context (right-click) menu, I suspect that it uses the existing Rights (and Permissions) of the user.

For example, a user must have Component Management rights to be able to tag a Component in a 'Release' or Template Management rights to tag a Page or Component Template.

[image]